# Is function $xy$ injective?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Is the function $g(x,y)=\frac {xy^5} {x^2+y^2}$ injective for $x,y \ne 0$? I think it is because $xy^5$ is injective as $y^5$ is injective. Thus the function is injective. Am I correct? If so, is there a more rigorous way to show it?

Comment: No. Consider $x=y=\pm1$. And in general for $y=x$ the function is equivalent to $\frac{x^4}{2}$ which is clearly non-injective

Comment: It's not injective. For every $y \in \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, we have $g(0,y) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xy^5$ is also not injective, you can take $x=0$, but $y=1,2$ respectively.

Comment: though it is explicitly specified $x,y\neq 0$...

Comment: then one can take $x=1,y=-1$ and $x=-1,y=1$, $xy^5$ also coincides..either cases show that "xy^5 is injective as y^5 is injective" is false.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is not injective.

First you can notice the symmetry $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$.

Secondly, even if you impose $x>0,y>0$ it is still not injective.

The reason is that $\dfrac{xy^5}{x^2+y^2}=k\iff (k)x^2-(y^5)x+(ky^2)=0$ is a quadratic thus solvable in $x$ for large enough values of $y$.

$$x=\dfrac{y^4\pm\sqrt{y^8-4k^2}}{2k}$$

For instance $(2,2)$ and $(4,64+4\sqrt{255})$ both give $g(x,y)=8$.